# recognize any type of link in content with php

Tags: php, url, hyperlink

I tried to make code to recognize link in content than in found this part of code : filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)
but i had realized  it just can recognize urls at the first of text content in the other cases url perhaps exsist at the middale of text  but the filter_var function can not recognize url so i exploaded every words of a content in a array and i turned code like:

```
$words = explode("\n", $text);

$eleman = sizeof($words);

for ($i=0; $i <= $eleman ; $i++) { 

  if (filter_var($words[$i], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {

    echo "yes it is a link...";
    return TRUE;

  }else{

    echo "no it isnt link...";
    return FALSE;
  }

}
```

but it still dosent recognize url in content.

Comment: I think you should be exploding with “ “ space character not “/n”

Comment: Please give a sample of `$text`.

Comment: I would rather explode it by whole line then check the whole line

Comment: I mean up to the end of each line

Comment: @TobyOkeke it doesn't matter with "\n" the text will be explode after each enter .

Comment: @user3783243 
$text ="this is a text whice contain 
www.google.com
 ";

Comment: @user3783243 and after explode variable $words ganna be like this 
Array
(
    [0] => this is a text whice contain
    [1] => www.google.com
 
)

Comment: The comment won't show new lines, please add the content to the question.